# Hybris 20.05 cronjob triggers not working

Tags: triggers, cron, jobs, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

My cronjobs, which exist in the backoffice and have been triggered and working for a long time according to the trigger time, have not been triggered for 4 days.
If I manually trigger the cronjobs they work. So there is no problem with data etc.
But the trigger does not automatically trigger the cronjob.
It was deployed to the machine 4 days ago, but there is no code problem, everything works fine on other machines.

What could this problem be caused by?
Thank you very much in advance for your help.

System version : 20.05

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned the machine off and on again and reset everything in the Backoffice and the triggers started working.

Answer (score 0):

It may resolve the issue:

How trigger works : CronJob having association of Trigger and trigger having the cron expression or freeScheduling and there is one more things in Hybris to notify system when trigger should get activated.

When trigger will activated part is stored in another type called **TriggerTask**.
TriggerTask hold the information of planned execution time and expiration date.

There might be possibility this got expired or some data might got corrupted,which gives trouble to execute the cronjob based on the trigger.

Solution:delete the Trigger Task Entry either via BO or using impex.
steps:bo->login> search types--> then put "TriggerTask" in advance search-->go for instance(with reference of below query)

```
select * from {TriggerTask as TT join Trigger as T on {T.pk}={TT.trigger}} where {T.pk}="<take is from cronjob>"
```

-->then delete the instance and **execute trigger impex again**